# facebook connect user information in DB

Tags: facebook

i,m planning to use facebook connect to connect to my site, i wanted to know if all

the websites using the facebook connect store the user information in there own DB?

if yes then which field is used to validate user from DB.

Comment: I have used facebook sdk with asp.net and able to get all the data which is reuired, i want to know if i should store this informtion in my user DB, and if user logs in next time using facebook connect , which field i should use to query from DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easy.  Store the user's Facebook User Id in your user database table. No two people share the same facebook user id.

Comment: is this the same case with Twitter?

Comment: Yep, sure is.  No two people can have the same twitter id (unless they share the password between the two)